# C# tutorial for "listening" to the line in device

Tags: c#, audio

I know the obvious answer is "try google..." but i have and I either end up with graphics or cmd-line tutorials, so...

Can anyone point I in the direction of a c# tutorial for "listening" to the audio line-in? Or is it straight forward with the right namespace included? Is it even possible without using directx or some such.

I want to detect external audio activity and report it on screen.

Cheers,

Comment: What do you mean by "listen"? Detect activity? Record audio?

Comment: I want to detect external audio activaty and report it on screen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This code sample looks like it has everything that you need: [VolumeMeter](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/directx/volumemeter.aspx)

Presumably you just need to change the code so that instead of rendering the current volume levels you could return a flag indicating whether "something" is going on.

It's using the [Managed DirectX](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/directx/default.aspx) library, which is a managed code wrapper for the native DirectX APIs.

Answer (score 2):

You need an external library to do that. These have .NET bindings:

- [FMOD](http://www.fmod.org/) is widely used in games, and has an opensource license (and a paid one).
- [BASS Audio Library](http://www.un4seen.com/) is another choice. It's a bit more lightweight.
- [IrrKlang](http://www.ambiera.com/irrklang/features.html) I haven't use this one, but I was told it is worth the money
- [NAudio](http://www.codeplex.com/naudio) I found just now, because I forgot the IrrKlang's name, and had to google for it. This one looks promising.

OR MDX can do this I think.

Answer (score 2):

check out the [VoiceRecorder](http://voicerecorder.codeplex.com) sample application on Codeplex which shows how to do this using [NAudio](http://naudio.codeplex.com). This [Coding4Fun article](http://blogs.msdn.com/coding4fun/archive/2009/10/08/9905168.aspx) explains it in more detail.